# Parent/ child hierarchy - SQL Server (tree)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parent-child

I am trying to get the structure of parent/ child via sql query.

I have this code:

state_code, description

```
A000
A010
B000
B010
B01A
B01B
B020
B02A
```

I want a structure like parent_id, element_id and desc

Such that:

```
A
A000
-01 (from A)
--A010
B
B000
-01
--B010
--B01A
-02
--
```

I tried it using this code, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
select distinct 
    SUBSTRING(REPLACE(state_cd,'0',''),1, LEN(REPLACE(state_cd, '0', '')) -1) AS parent_id, REPLACE(state_cd,'0','') state_id,
    state_cd,
    desc_1
from 
    CATEGORYSTRUCTURE 
inner join 
    CATEGORYITEMS on CATEGORYSTRUCTURE.struct_id = CATEGORYITEMS.struct_id 
left join
    STATECODES on key_1 = state_cd
where
    state_type = '22'

UNION ALL

select distinct  
    SUBSTRING(REPLACE(state_cd,'0',''),1, LEN(REPLACE(state_cd, '0', '')) -1) AS parent_id,
    REPLACE(state_cd,'0','') state_id,
    stat_cd,
    desc_1
from 
    CATEGORYITEMS 
inner join
    STATECODES on key_1 = state_cd
where 
    state_type = '22'
```

My result:

```
parent_id   stat_id stat_cd desc_1
    O   O000    11
    P   P000    Pa)
    Q   Q000    prod
    R   R000    Zus
    S   S000    Ver
    T   T000    Pack
A   A1  A010    Get
A   A1  A100    Kakt
A   A3  A030    Kol
A   A7  A070    Milk
A   A8  A080    Spt
A1  A11 A110    Lo
A1  A1A A01A    Hcht
```

What I want is everything under respective characters

```
    A   A7  A070    Milk
    A   A8  A080    Spt
    A   A11 A110    Lo
    A1  A1A A01A    Hcht
```

Comment: Smells like a bad database design to me. You should consider refactoring your table and add a nullable parent id column.

Comment: Give more sample data please. This is not clear.

Comment: Your result how to map `parent_id`, `element_id` and `desc`?

Comment: The problem is.. I am unable to get A1, D22 etc under respective characters.

i.e. in last two lines in result. 

column 1: A , Column 2 : A1 ..
i want it to be as  A1

Comment: What are parent of B10A and B01A and why?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what exactly you want, But I think this query can help you:

```
SELECT state_cd
    , SUBSTRING(state_cd,1,1) As Parent0
    , CASE WHEN state_cd Like '__[^0]_' THEN SUBSTRING(state_cd,2,2) ELSE '' END As Parent1
    , CASE WHEN state_cd Like '___[^0]' THEN SUBSTRING(state_cd,4,1) ELSE '' END As Parent2
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Please check my result and description. I just updated it.

Comment: I suggest you to use **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6)** to store your sample data ;).